# UINavigationController back button title color

Tags: swift

I am trying to set the color of the back button for a view embedded in a navigation controller.

I have successfully changed the color of the button, but the text remains grey.

[image]

I have implemented the following code in the view did load.

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.75, blue:0.76, alpha:1.0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white ,NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.init(name: "Montserrat-Bold", size: 17)!]
```

Comment: Are you talking about the "Get Help" text?

Comment: yes, I don't know what is setting it to be grey. I have now tried         navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
and         navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
neither work.

Comment: Okay but you need to to think about why it is grey. Get rid of all your navigation bar code and just say, in the app delegate, `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white; UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black` and you will see that all your navigation bars are black and all the text is white _including the back item_. So you must be counteracting that somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view controller you want to go back to, add to viewDidLoad():

```
if let title = navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title {
    let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    barItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red], for: .normal)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barItem
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` to get access to the button itself, and you can also set it to a new `UIBarButtonItem` if you want. This only sets the back button of the current view controller, so if you want to change it on every view controller, you have to set it for each page. Mark Moeykens has a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QiPG_2T2L3M&index=7&list=PLaaElgrtMXjJl-l2U6OSAkBN3dNT34WB2&t=0s) on it if that helps as well.